# Any Idea of make Input and the button inline? Bootsrap v5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to make my input textbox and button inline but if i remove d-flex class from div, i cant justify by content to center. any ideas to make them inline or justify content?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Movies</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->

    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body class="bg-image shadow-2-strong">
    <div class="mask">
      <div class="container d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center text-center h-100">
        <div>
          <h1 class="mb-3">THE MOVIE SCOPE!</h1>
          <h5 class="mb-4">search with movie titles</h5>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required />
          <form action="/" method="post">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg">click</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)">© 2021 Copyright Danuja Jayasuriya</div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's how it looks now

[image]

Comment: What do you mean you can't justify your content to center without it ? You should be able to use `margin: 0 auto;` to center these things. I'm not sure why you're using a double layer of `<div>`s around the actual content, pointless in your example (but maybe your live version has more stuff in it that does require it). -- i think that bootstrap provides the class `mx-auto` to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a div to cover `<input> and <form>` with the class `d-flex`, adding padding or margin to customize the space between textbox and button. For example, I added `ms-4` to the button div.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Movies</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />
</head>

<body class="bg-image shadow-2-strong">
  <div class="mask">
    <div class="container d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center text-center h-100">
      <h1 class="mb-3">THE MOVIE SCOPE!</h1>
      <h5 class="mb-4">search with movie titles</h5>
      <div>
        <div class="d-flex">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required />
          <form action="/" method="post">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg ms-4">click</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)">© 2021 Copyright Danuja Jayasuriya</div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```